# Como definir as dimensões de uma página HTML?

Tags: html

Estou a utilizar o DreamWeaver e agora é que experimentei a página na internet, e a página fica muito larga. Como consigo controlar a largura e altura da página?

Comment: Você poderia colocar um pouco do seu código? Caso contrário, fica muito difícil adivinhar o que está acontecendo contigo.

Answer (score 6):

Podes utilizar os atributos `height` (altura) e `width` (largura) em pixeis ou em percentagem no estilo do *body* ou por CSS. Mas é boa pratica ser no CSS.

**No CSS:**

```
body {
   height:200px; 
   width:100px;
}
```

e/ou

```
 body {
    height:100%; 
    width:50%;
 }
```

**No HTML:**

```
<body style="height:100%; width:50%;">
```

Comment: E Normalmente qual é o tamanho da pagina internet.ou seja, A pagina para cima e para baixo depende mas em termos de largura?

Comment: Isso depende do que queres, mas se fizeres `width:100%` vai ocupar-te a janela do *browser* por completo.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode colocar a centralizar a página e ainda colocar proporcional assim:

```
.wrapper{
max-width: 1000px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```